Proof DFT of d/dn x[n] is proportional to jk * (DFT of x[n]) = jk * X[k]
So I'm familiar with how the derivative of an aperiodic, continuous signal can be found by taking its Fourier transform, multiplying by $j \omega$, and then inverse transforming. Great explanation.
I'd like to see the analogous derivation for the DFT, to work with discrete, periodic signals. I gather the answer should be that we multiply by $j \omega_k$ where $\omega_k \in \{\frac{2\pi}{N}k\}, k\in \{-\frac{N}{2}+1, ... \frac{N}{2}\}$, but, as far as I'm aware, we can no longer do the integration by parts trick in discrete time.
Would we derive the relationship first and then discretize? Why do we have to use $k\in \{-\frac{N}{2}+1, ... \frac{N}{2}\}$ rather than $k\in \{0, ... N-1\}$? Why, as stated here, do we have to to take the $N^{th}$ Fourier coefficient to be 0 rather than   multiplying by $j\frac{2\pi}{N}\frac{N}{2} = j\pi$?

Please spell out in detail what you mean by differentiating with respect to $n$.  $n$ is not a continuous variable.

To echo Dilip's comment: In order to answer the question as asked you need to define what exactly $d\dn$ means for a discrete variable. You cannot proof an identity for something that's undefined in the first place.

Here is a derivation for discrete derivative beginning with continuous signals.

You're right that if $n$ is a discrete variable, then technically the derivative doesn't exist. I'm an engineer, not a mathematician, so I sweep such things under the rug usually. Apologies. What I mean is that $x[n]$ is can really be thought of as plugging integer $n$ in to an inverse transform of some kind, wherein we have sines and cosines of $n$, where $n$ isn't necessarily discrete. So in spirit you can take a derivative of that function, then resample it at integers.

This seems really useful. Reading now: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/fft-deriv.pdf

Okay, my questions are best answered by Steven G. Johnson, of MIT Applied Mathematics.
Indeed, the reasons why we use the lower-absolute-value wavenumbers and why the $N^{th}$ term disappears in the 1st derivative are really subtle.

I think this is an ill posed question. For continuous signals the derivative is defined as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
However this definition doesn't work for discrete signals. $\lim_{\Delta n \to 0}$ is nonsensical if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. $n$ can be 0 or 1 but it can't be anything in between.
There are various different ways to define a "discrete derivative" but they all have their pros and cons and there is no single "correct" version. Differentiation is an LTI process but it's not bandlimited. It's kind of the opposite since the amplitude rises with frequency. Any discrete implementation of a differentiator needs to manage significant amounts of aliasing.

Then give me the version where we take the derivative first and then discretize. We take derivatives of sampled signals all the time. That's the notion by which I mean derivative. I'm trying to take spectral derivatives in a computer, where everything is sampled. But those samples represents a continuous function via some kind of continuous basis functions, like the Fourier basis.

Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302160/correct-way-to-calculate-numeric-derivative-in-discrete-time

No, that's finite difference. I am talking about spectral derivatives.

What do you mean by an LTI process being / not being bandlimited? Is that a property of the impulse response of the process?

@OlliNiemitalo: Sorry, that's a bit of a sloppy terminology. What I mean is that the magnitude of the transfer function isn't 0 above a certain frequency and hence the impulse response cannot be sampled without aliasing.

@PavelKomarov, I guess you can multiply the DFT with $-j\omega$ and do an inverse DFT, but why ? The DFT implies that the signal is periodic and discrete in both domains, so you in reality you are not multiplying with a line but with a sawtooth and you get lots of time domain aliasing.

Yes, you are effectively multiplying by a sawtooth. But this kind of thing is done. I'm essentially trying to derive the third step of the algorithm on p78 here: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/1.9780898719598.ch8. I think @Ash's answer comes very close to what I want, and it may be as I suspected that you have to discretize after taking derivatives https://www.wavewalkerdsp.com/2021/11/24/derivative-filter-impulse-response-derivation/

I think I figured it out. Edit: The below is wrong past a certain point, so I've struck some of it out.
Say we have a discrete signal of length $N$, $y = [y_0, y_1, ... y_{N-1}]$.
The DFT is:
$$ a_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} y_n e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$$
$$ = y_0 e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}0k} + y_1 e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}k} + ... + y_{N-1}e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}(N-1)k}$$
If I take the derivative w.r.t. $n$ right now, I'll end up multiplying by $-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k$, but this should be equivalent to multiplying by a positive due to periodicity:
We're traveling around the unit circle in the negative direction, but we could travel in the positive direction instead, because $ e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} = e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} (-n) k} = e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} (-n+N) k} = e^{j (\frac{2\pi}{N} (-n) + 2\pi) k}$, and integer offsets of $2\pi$ don't change the value.
Likewise, the values of $y$ repeat, so $y_0 = y_N = y_{-N}$ and $y_{N-1} = y_{N-1-N} = y_{-1}$.
Therefore:
$$ a_k = y_{-N} e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}(-N)k} + y_{1-N} e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}(-1+N)k} + ... + y_{-1}e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}(-1)k} $$
$$ = y_{-N} e^{+j \frac{2\pi}{N}Nk} + y_{1-N} e^{+j \frac{2\pi}{N}(1-N)k} + ... + y_{-1}e^{+j \frac{2\pi}{N}k} $$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^{N} y_{-n} e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$$
Now I can take the derivative w.r.t. $n$ of this thing to get:
$$ \frac{d}{dn} a_k = \frac{d}{dn} \sum_{n=1}^{N} y_{-n} e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N}nk} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} y_{-n} \frac{d}{dn} e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N}nk} $$
because the $y_n$ are constants to the derivative.
$$ = j \frac{2\pi}{N}k \sum_{n=1}^{N} y_{-n} e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N}nk} = j \frac{2\pi}{N}k \cdot a_k$$

The way you wrote this now, it looks like you're taking the derivative with respect to a dummy variable, which is very illegal. I could replace the variable that is summed over with any other variable.

I really think you should pay attention to what AccidentalTaylorExpansion and what @Hilmar said

I'm still trying to find the derivation I want, but I have recognized a major error here: I need to do d/dn x[n], not d/dn a_k! What I'm insisting on is that x[n] can be thought of as discrete points along a continuous function, like a Fourier expansion, so taking derivatives of those sines and cosines can in fact make sense. But what I've done here is obviously some mathematical casuistry that isn't right.
